# Warning: Invalid argument in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

This file has an error invalid argument supplied for foreach. Does anyone solve this issue. I tried lot of time but i could not find it,I don't know how to solve this. Here is My code:

```
 <?php
    include('connect.php'); 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM product";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $output ='<table class="table table-stripped table-bordered">
    <tr><th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Product Type</th>
    <th>Product Rate</th>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Insert</th>
    </tr>';
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        foreach (mysqli_num_rows($result) as $row) {
            $output .= '<tr>
                <td width="40%">'.$row["product_name"].'</td>
                <td width="40%">'.$row["product_type"].'</td>
                <td width="40%">'.$row["product_rate"].'</td>
                <td width="40%">'.$row["brand"].'</td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <button type="button" name="edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edit" id="'.$row["id"].'">Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.$row["id"].'">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }

    else
    {
        $output .='<tr>
        <td colspan ="4" align="center"> No data Found</td>
        </tr>' ;
    }

    $output .= '</table>';
    echo $output;
     ?>
```

Comment: mysqli_num_rows() Returns the number of rows in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_num_rows` function returns a number, not an array. You probably want to use [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

```
foreach (mysqli_fetch_all($result) as $row) {

}
```

Comment: how to solve this problem -product name,type,rate,brand all are undefined ...in tha above code

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you made is that you use the `num_rows` function in the foreach. I always prefer to use a while-loop with a fetch.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $output .= '<tr>
                <td width="40%">'.$row["product_name"].'</td>
                <td width="40%">'.$row["product_type"].'</td>
                <td width="40%">'.$row["product_rate"].'</td>
                <td width="40%">'.$row["brand"].'</td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <button type="button" name="edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edit" id="'.$row["id"].'">Edit</button>
                </td>
                <td width="10%">
                    <button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.$row["id"].'">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) is the solution to your problem. [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) requires an array to iterate it and the earlier method provides you the same.

Answer (score 0):

[mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) will return row as associative array, if you want complete rows as associative array you must use [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: Please add an example and its explanation here so that it's more convenient for everyone

Comment: product name,type,rate,brand all are undefined error occur

Comment: use

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

instead of 

foreach (mysqli_num_rows($result) as $row) {

Comment: and if you want to use foreach then it should be like this:-

$result =  mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row) {

Comment: @JituRawat Your proposed solution for foreach changes the logic though and fetches all. If you want to use foreach you want to use iterators e.g. `foreach($mysqli->query('SELECT x from y') as $row) { }`